# Check if a URL is valid in elixir

Tags: elixir

I want to check if a given URL is valid, ideally if the url resolves too.

Firstly, how would I go about just checking the string validity (i.e. regex)

and secondly, is there a way that I can see if the URL actually resolves to a resource on the internet?

Thanks

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Instead of reaching out for a regex I would use the URI package to textually validate the URI, and then check if the host name resolves through :inet.gethostbyname:

```
iex(1)> URI.parse("http://google.com/")
%URI{authority: "google.com", fragment: nil, host: "google.com",
path: "/", port: 80, query: nil, scheme: "http", userinfo: nil}
```

Note the "host" field of the URI struct. If it's a relative resource then this will be `nil`. Additionally scheme will be nil if the scheme, i.e. `http://`, or `ftp://` is missing. The path should also be there("/") even if it's just the root path of the site. Your validation then is whether any of these are `nil` or not, something like this:

```
defmodule Validation do
  def validate_uri(str) do
    uri = URI.parse(str)
    case uri do
      %URI{scheme: nil} -> {:error, uri}
      %URI{host: nil} -> {:error, uri}
      %URI{path: nil} -> {:error, uri}
      uri -> {:ok, uri}
    end 
  end 
end

{:ok, uri} = Validation.validate_uri("http://google.com/")
```

You can then pass this "valid" uri to [:inet.gethostbyname/1](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/inet.html#gethostbyname-1)

```
iex(18)> :inet.gethostbyname(to_char_list a.host)
{:ok, {:hostent, 'google.com', [], :inet, 4, [{216, 58, 217, 46}]}}
```

If for whatever reason this fails `:inet.gethostbyname/1` will return `{:error, :nxdomain}`

Comment: Thank you very much :) You've saved me from a 500 character regular expression :)

Comment: It is worth noting that URI.parse does not really validate the URL but rather expects one to be valid. You should check at least scheme, host and path.

Comment: @JoséValim Good point, I've updated based on those suggestions.

Comment: In practice this method doesn't validate a URL at all. `www.example.com` is valid and so is `www.example`  - because of this I would say the accepted answer is incorrect

Comment: @Theston.EFox I think you missed the latter part of this 2-part answer. `:inet.gethostbyname/1` is vital for checking that the URL resolves. So `www.example` would not be valid because you get `{:error, :nxdomain}`

Comment: @TalkLittle yeah you're right that would be the missing piece to the puzzle :)

Comment: Look at https://github.com/johnotander/is_url, it does checks similar to those which are suggested in this answer.

Comment: Here's a [regex-based library](https://hexdocs.pm/valid_url) from a [larger discussion](https://mathiasbynens.be/demo/url-regex) with a recommended source [gist](https://gist.github.com/dperini/729294).

Comment: note: in most most cases you'd probably want to treat `"http://example.com"` as a valid url, whereas this solution would treat it as invalid because of the missing path / trailing slash.

Comment: here's an example for an ecto changeset validation https://gist.github.com/atomkirk/74b39b5b09c7d0f21763dd55b877f998

Comment: As of Elixir 1.13.0 you can use `URI.new("some_url")` to parse and validate a URI. More info: https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/1.13.1/URI.html#new/