# How to validate url in elixir?

Tags: elixir

I want to validate uris like:

```
http://vk.com
http://semantic-ui.com/collections/menu.html
https://translate.yandex.ru/?text=poll&lang=en-ru
```

and not

```
www.vk.com
abdeeej
http://vk
```

but haven't found either package of native code implementation for it.

How can I do that?

Comment: `http://vk` is a perfectly valid URL. Do you want to reject URLs where the hostname doesn't contain any "."?

Comment: Why do you think that `http://vk` is a perfect url? Where is the domain name?

Comment: `http://localhost` is a valid URL. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20573488/why-does-html5-form-validation-allow-emails-without-a-dot

Comment: You're right, but it's theoretically. Practically, have you ever though I need to have `localhost` in production project? :P

Comment: Seems like this was also answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30696761/check-if-a-url-is-valid-in-elixir

Comment: About the question "Why do you think that http://vk is a perfect url? Where is the domain name? " : the domain name in the URL is "vk" (or "vk." in FQDN form). Nobody ever said that domain names must have more than one label.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

All of those are technically valid URLs according to the spec so `URI.parse/1` returns a `%URI{}` struct for all, but if you want to reject domains without a `scheme` and a dot in the `host`, you can do:

```
valid? = fn url ->
  uri = URI.parse(url)
  uri.scheme != nil && uri.host =~ "."
end
```

Test:

```
urls = [
  "http://vk.com",
  "http://semantic-ui.com/collections/menu.html",
  "https://translate.yandex.ru/?text=poll&lang=en-ru",
  "www.vk.com",
  "abdeeej",
  "http://vk"
]

urls |> Enum.map(valid?) |> IO.inspect
```

Output:

```
[true, true, true, false, false, false]
```

Comment: Nobody offered something else. Sad! But thanks to you!

Comment: This answer has invalid syntax. `uri.scheme != nil` should be `!is_nil(uri.scheme)` or you will encounter a runtime error.

Comment: @Brian The `&&` operator will return `false` for a `nil` value on the left hand side so just `uri.scheme && ...` suffices too.

Comment: `=~` will also raise if `uri.host` is `nil`, so the complete check should be `not is_nil(uri.scheme) and not is_nil(uri.host) and uri.host =~ "."`

Answer (score 4):

This solution is more complete:

```elixir
  def validate_url(changeset, field, opts \\ []) do
    validate_change(changeset, field, fn _, value ->
      case URI.parse(value) do
        val(%URI{scheme: nil}) ->
          "is missing a scheme (e.g. https)"

        %URI{host: nil} ->
          "is missing a host"

        %URI{host: host} ->
          case :inet.gethostbyname(Kernel.to_charlist(host)) do
            {:ok, _} -> nil
            {:error, _} -> "invalid host"
          end
      end
      |> case do
        error when is_binary(error) -> [{field, Keyword.get(opts, :message, error)}]
        _ -> []
      end
    end)
  end
```

Cribbed from https://gist.github.com/atomkirk/74b39b5b09c7d0f21763dd55b877f998

Answer (score 2):

Since elixir `1.13.0`, another way to validate a url is using `URI.new/1`. It errors on poorly encoded urls and more stricter compared to `URI.parse`

Caution: URI.new/1 fails on poorly encoded or not encoded url such as url with a space in it which is not encoded and returns error.

```
# Without encoding, notice the space in the url
iex(1)> URI.new("https://testdomain/Teams/Odense Boldklub.png")
{:error, ":"}

# After encoding URL
iex(9)> URI.encode("https://testdomain/Teams/Odense Boldklub.png") |> URI.new
{:ok,
 %URI{
   scheme: "https",
   userinfo: nil,
   host: "testdomain",
   port: 443,
   path: "/Teams/Odense%20Boldklub.png",
   query: nil,
   fragment: nil
 }}
```